# Creating alert window in browser with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want create alert window in browser.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=geckodriver_path,
    log_path=geckodriver_log_path
)
browser.get(url)
```

To create alert window I doing:

```
browser.execute_script("alert('qwer');")
```

or

```
browser.execute_script("return alert('qwer');")
```

or

```
browser.execute_script("return (function(){alert('qwer'); return 0;})();")
```

In all cases alert window was displayed. But in all cases I have an Exception: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to find value field`.

**What is right way to create alert window?**

Comment: Can you try a different browser? Chromedriver for example. It appears to be a Firefox-related issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seem to be `geckodriver` issue. Despite of generated `"Failed to find value field"` exception you still can handle opened alert, so you might apply below workaround:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    browser.execute_script("alert('qwer');")
except WebDriverException:
    pass
browser.switch_to.alert.text # output is "qwer"
browser.switch_to.alert.accept() # alert closed
```

...or, as was mentioned in comments, you can use `Chrome`, `IE`, etc